# How to run multiple servers on one computer but with different IP Address

Tags: windows, networking, webserver

I want to run multiple servers on one computer where every server have different IP address. It is just for simulation purpose. I have a windows laptop. I want to simulate distributed computing where I have a master server which listens to client and gives jobs to other server to perform task from queue. So for simulation purpose i want to show that my servers are running on different ip address and my master server is connecting to other server. But in practical they are all on the same pc 
How can I do it?

Comment: What kind of computer?  What OS?  Do you want multiple IP addresses on the same physical network port?

Comment: Please check the new edit @rtx13. Thankyou for your reply

Comment: I don't have a windows system handy, but you should be able to readily assign multiple IP addresses to the same network adapter.  This should be somewhere under IP settings for the network adapter.

Comment: Can I change all servers have same IP address but they listen on different ports. Will it cause any delay in processing@rtx13

Comment: That depends on your server.  If every instance of the server can bind to a different port, then yes you can start multiple servers on the same IP address, each bound to a different port.  This really depends on the server software and the ability to configure it.

Comment: Thankyou for the leads @rtx13